# Redirect SXA site url matching query string using IIS Redirect Module

Tags: sxa, url-rewrite, seo

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 and SXA 1.7.1 and we are using Sitecore Redirect module . There are some Redirects in system which have query string Parameter like the example mentioned below:

**OLD URL:** `xxxx/yyy/page/19/?paged=20`

**NEW URL:** `/aaaa/bbbbb`

Since entering Query string is not allowed due to usage of the Name Value List field type for Mappings field and it allows keys containing letters and numbers due to the `Validate()` method in it.

Is there a way that we can use `IIS` Redirects Rule to achieve this kind of functionality

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to answer this question with certainty as it may be a bit of trial and error, but you can try this rewrite rule

```
<rule name="1" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
  <match url="xxxx/yyy/page/19/?paged=20" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/aaaa/bbbbb"/>
</rule>
```